# How to separate a specific portion out of a string and into its own column in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, street-address

Say I have the following data set:

| Address_1 | Address_2 |
| --- | --- |
| PO BOX 123 |  |
| COMPANY NAME ONE 1234 ROSE AVE | STE 100 |
| 456 PETUNIA WAY FIFTH FLOOR |  |
| COMPANY NAME TWO PO BOX 78910 |  |
| COMPANY NAME THREE 1112 DAISY ST THIRD FLOOR |  |

I'm trying to figure out two things here -

1. How to separate any company name prior to the start of an address. Basically, if the string doesn't start with 'PO' or any sequence of numbers (ex: 456, 1112, etc.), then take that portion out and put it into a new column
2. How to get the substring directly to the left of the word 'FLOOR' to result into a new column. It would be nice if I could pull over 'FIFTH FLOOR' together, but if not I can always concatenate ' FLOOR' to the end of the new column

I want my data to result as below:

| Address_1 | Address_2 | Company_name | ADDR_LNE_1_NM | ADDR_LNE_2_NM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PO BOX 123 |  |  | PO BOX 123 |  |
| COMPANY NAME ONE 1234 ROSE AVE | STE 100 | COMPANY NAME ONE | 1234 ROSE AVE | STE 100 |
| 456 PETUNIA WAY FIFTH FLOOR |  |  | 456 PETUNIA WAY | FIFTH FLOOR |
| COMPANY NAME TWO PO BOX 78910 |  | COMPANY NAME TWO | PO BOX 78910 |  |
| COMPANY NAME THREE 1112 DAISY ST THIRD FLOOR |  | COMPANY NAME THREE | 1112 DAISY ST | THIRD FLOOR |

Here is the current code I have for separating the substring ' FLOOR' out. I just need to know how to modify or change this code to include the 'FIFTH' and 'THIRD' (and any other written out number) in there like in the output. Maybe by pulling everything until the first space to the left of ' FLOOR'?

```
CASE
    WHEN 
        database.table.Address_1 like '% FLOOR%'
        THEN 
            TRIM(SUBSTR(database.table.Address_1, 0, INSTR(database.table.Address_1, ' FLOOR')-1))

END "ADDR_LNE_1_NM",


CASE
    WHEN
        database.table.Address_1 like '% FLOOR%'
        THEN
            TRIM(SUBSRT(database.table.Address_1, DECODE(INSTR(database.table.Address_1, ' FLOOR'), 0, NULL, INSTR(database.table.Address_1, ' FLOOR'))))

END "ADDR_LNE_2_NM"
```

I don't have any code for separating the company name. That one I'm at a loss for.

Thank you!

Comment: Best way to have whatever system collects this information to parse it for you. Otherwise, this can be very difficult or impossible in some scenarios. For example, if you have a company name that includes a number (such as AND 1) then you're out of luck.

Comment: If you have `FLOOR `in the first column and `STE` in a second, what will be the result?

Comment: This feels like a job for regex - and god help the person who has to debug it :)

Comment: Also, not all addresses start with a number or PO Box, making it another scenario where you cannot distinguish where the Company Name ends and the Address begins. And also keep in mind that many companies have the word "Floor" in them.

Comment: Also consider: `West 34 Street` and `Fifth Avenue`.

Comment: If this is a learning project - I would go with `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`,  otherwise the address should be properly captured and sanitized before it gets stored in DB.

Comment: Does it have to be done in a single SQL query? What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @Isolated - For an address starting with anything else other than PO box or a number sequence, I can make the adjustments as needed for whats in our database and hopefully eventually expand upon it so its applicable to more than just ours. 

I'm more so unsure in how to reference if a strng begins with a specific character, rather than if that character exists anywhere throughout the string.

Comment: @PM 77-1 - I'm only hoping to search for values to the left of substring ' FlOOR' until the next space (' ') to the left, rather than searching for 'FIFTH' specifically. 

I have code that extracts things like '5TH FLOOR' or '42ND FLOOR' from a string, so hypothetically, I could write out every conversion by replacing anything that says 'FIFTH' to '5TH' and so on, and my existing code would pick it up. However, i'm trying to avoid entering in all those conversions if possible so everything is more concise

Comment: @PM 77-1 -FLOOR in 1st and STE in 2nd column, good point! All substring extractions im performing are done in both Address_1 and Address_2 columns.

My final select statement for ADDR_LNE_2_NM is currently set to pick up the extracted value (if any) from Address_2's ADDR_LNE_2, if thats null then the already existing value (if any) in Address_2, and if thats null then the extracted value (if any) from Address_1's ADDR_LNE_2.

Hope that makes sense. I can add in a statement that says if both Address_2's ADDR_LNE_2 and Address_1's ADDR_LNE_2 arent null, then to concat both together, thank u!

Comment: @Randy I'm currently utilizing regex throughout my query and am okay using it if you know how to solve either of these issues with it, i can not figure it out for the life of me

Comment: @BobbyDurrett ideally yes its all in once, however im currently using a CTE and imagine ill be using multiple in the end result. oracle version 21.4.3

Comment: @PM77-1 It's not for a learning project, the data hasnt been cleaned up before being put into the data base for over a decade, so the plan is to clean it up on its way out when we need it. I'm using regexp_substring in other parts of my query but i have no idea how to apply that to this situation. Ive spent hours and hours and hours trying to figure this out but I'm at a complete loss. I'm not expecting the result to be perfect, but if you know of any way to achieve either of these outcomes I would appreciate it so much.

Comment: Parsing addresses is an unsolved problem. If there was a solution, SQL would not be the language used.

Answer (score 0):

I would work with the regular expression functions that Oracle offers:
`REGEXP_SUBSTR()` to cut out the pieces on floor and company name, and `REGEXP_REPLACE()` to remove the "n-th FLOOR" part from the address:

```
WITH
indata(Address_1,Address_2) AS (
          SELECT 'PO BOX 123'                                  ,NULL      FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'COMPANY NAME ONE 1234 ROSE AVE'              ,'STE 100' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT '456 PETUNIA WAY FIFTH FLOOR'                 ,NULL      FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'COMPANY NAME TWO PO BOX 78910'               ,NULL      FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'COMPANY NAME THREE 1112 DAISY ST THIRD FLOOR',NULL      FROM dual
)
SELECT
  address_1
, address_2
, REGEXP_SUBSTR(address_1,'^.+ (?=(PO BOX|\d+ \w+))') AS compname
, REGEXP_REPLACE(
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(address_1,'(PO BOX \d+|\d+).*$')
  , '\w+ FLOOR'
  , ''
  )  AS addr_ln_1
, NVL(REGEXP_SUBSTR(address_1,'\w+ FLOOR$'),address_2) AS addr_ln_2
FROM indata;
```

| ADDRESS_1 | ADDRESS_2 | COMPNAME | ADDR_LN_1 | ADDR_LN_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PO BOX 123 | *null* | *null* | PO BOX 123 | *null* |
| COMPANY NAME ONE 1234 ROSE AVE | STE 100 | *null* | 1234 ROSE AVE | STE 100 |
| 456 PETUNIA WAY FIFTH FLOOR | *null* | *null* | 456 PETUNIA WAY | FIFTH FLOOR |
| COMPANY NAME TWO PO BOX 78910 | *null* | *null* | PO BOX 78910 | *null* |
| COMPANY NAME THREE 1112 DAISY ST THIRD FLOOR | *null* | *null* | 1112 DAISY ST | THIRD FLOOR |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8vqSb_I-)